# Vue - Switch between two different templates

Tags: vue.js, templates

I've been developing a new Vue project to control the connected devices from one point, I've been working on an admin template and it's all good but there is something that I want to learn and implement to this application.

Let's say I want to change the whole frontend template (the admin template that I'm using now) and use a new design, how can I implement the whole existing application to a new template? For example, when you start creating a Wordpress page, it gives you different templates and you choose some of them and start designing the website... Maybe after six months you want to change that design and you simply click and switch to a new template and all the existing content will be migrated to the new template. That is exactly what I want to do with Vuejs.

I have to do this project, which I prepared with the existing theme, dynamically, as if I will pass it to another theme in the future. When switching my existing project to a new theme, instead of copying all the components and their related scripts, I want to be able to switch just like in Wordpress by simply throwing the theme file into the project. How can I add this functionality to the project?

Comment: Hi, You can create multiple templates and then on the basis of some conditions can change the template. You can use a dynamic component to do this. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: I know that but the the app will not be created to have more than one template. Let's say the customer or the company decided to change the theme and designed a new one. So today, the theme is not existing in the project folder but it will be... So the project should be ready to be migrated to a new theme. That is my real problem actually

Comment: When you say new theme, are you talking about CSS? or HTML and CSS?

Comment: New HTML and CSS. You can think of this as a transition from an admin panel theme to a new one. For example the first one has a sidebar to display the menus, but the new one will have a horizontal topbar...